# SCAN function in excel returns VALUE error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is wrong with this formula?. It works few times but stopped working suddenly.

```
=SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(10),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v))
```

[image]

Comment: Check your office license and for updates.

Comment: The syntax is correct.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the syntax, the same formula is working on my end. Here is a **[snippet](https://imgur.com/gallery/2cfFxXB)**.  Better to contact the MSFT Support once, I once had an issue with `REDUCE()` function.

Comment: Hardly related, but you could use the 'scanless' formula `=LET(terms,10,n,SEQUENCE(terms),n*(n+1)/2)`or write your own Lambda function e.g. `GetTriSeq`, by using `=LAMBDA(terms,LET(n,SEQUENCE(terms),n*(n+1)/2))` in the *Name Manager* which you could utilize with e.g. `=GetTriSeq(10)`.